# Speed up complex query

Tags: php, mysql, database, join, query-performance

I've two queries. The first one counts the results and the second one gets the date that I need.

My database has ~150000 rows. They take some while to run.

How can i speed things up?

```
$sql ="SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT articolo.id) FROM articolo
        INNER JOIN l_articolo_formato ON l_articolo_formato.id_articolo=articolo.id
        INNER JOIN formato ON formato.id=l_articolo_formato.id_formato
        INNER JOIN l_articolo_genere ON l_articolo_genere.id_articolo=articolo.id
        INNER JOIN genere ON genere.id=l_articolo_genere.id_genere
        INNER JOIN l_articolo_rental ON l_articolo_rental.id_articolo=articolo.id
        INNER JOIN rental ON rental.id=l_articolo_rental.id_rental
        WHERE  formato.nome = :var_value AND  genere.adult = 0 AND rental.nome ='0'" ;
$s=$pdo->prepare($sql);
$s->bindValue(':var_value',$var_value);
$s->execute();
$num_ris=$s->fetchColumn(0);


// il numero totale di pagine
$all_pages = ceil($num_ris / $ris_per_pag);

//la ricerca
$sql ="SELECT articolo.id,articolo.titolo,articolo.anno_produzione,articolo.immagine,articolo.prezzo_dettaglio FROM articolo
        INNER JOIN l_articolo_formato ON l_articolo_formato.id_articolo=articolo.id
        INNER JOIN formato ON formato.id=l_articolo_formato.id_formato
        INNER JOIN l_articolo_genere ON l_articolo_genere.id_articolo=articolo.id
        INNER JOIN genere ON genere.id=l_articolo_genere.id_genere
        INNER JOIN l_articolo_rental ON l_articolo_rental.id_articolo=articolo.id
        INNER JOIN rental ON rental.id=l_articolo_rental.id_rental
        WHERE  formato.nome = :var_value AND  genere.adult = 0 AND rental.nome ='0' LIMIT $first,$ris_per_pag" ;
$s=$pdo->prepare($sql);
$s->bindValue(':var_value',$var_value);
$s->execute();
$s->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
```

So this is the explain of the first query

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  articolo    index   PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   NULL    42092   Using index
1   SIMPLE  l_articolo_formato  ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   uz49pu08_StoreDb.articolo.id    1   Using index
1   SIMPLE  l_articolo_rental   ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   uz49pu08_StoreDb.l_articolo_formato.id_articolo 1   Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  l_articolo_genere   ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   uz49pu08_StoreDb.l_articolo_formato.id_articolo 1   Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  genere  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   uz49pu08_StoreDb.l_articolo_genere.id_genere    1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  rental  ALL PRIMARY NULL    NULL    NULL    2   Using where; Using join buffer
1   SIMPLE  formato eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   uz49pu08_StoreDb.l_articolo_formato.id_formato  1   Using where
```

Comment: So have you done an EXPLAIN to see what indexes your query is using?

Comment: Can you explain to me what i need to do?

Comment: Execute your queries with `EXPLAIN` prepended to them (so `EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(.....`) to see how MySQL executes them internally. This is useful to determine which indexes (if any) are used for which joins and where clauses.

Comment: 150000 rows is not that big. you may just need to optimize your tables' indexes.

Comment: OK, just added the explain of the first query, what i can do now?What i can understand from it?

Comment: You could also try to rewrite queries without using INNER JOIN and try to use just nested SELECT, I have similar issue once and this solution worked well (but I'm not an expert).

Comment: An index on `rental.id` might be a start

Comment: rental.id is already an index, every "id" column that you see are index for his tables

Comment: Well for whatever reason, it's not using that index in the query

Comment: OK, some suggestions?